# Google Conversions Not Working - Script Won't Load

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I have an AdWords campaign for which I have set up conversion tracking.  Google generated some code which I placed after the the begin body tag:

```
  <!-- Google Code for Sign Up Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 999999999;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "3";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "redacted";
    var google_conversion_value = 0;
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/999999999/?label=redacted&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

It seems to work in Safari and IE.  But it in Firefox and Chrome, loading `conversion.js` fails.  In Firefox the status says `aborted`, in Chrome `failed`.  No status code.

I've tried putting this code in various places including head and at the bottom.

Ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do you have Adblock Plus or similar ad-blocking software installed? Adblock Plus will block the download of conversion.js, so you will need to disable ad-blocking on your site for testing.

Comment: adblock was also blocking google's ad service js: http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js "pausing" adblock fixed this too

Comment: I had *.google.com white-listed but...now I feel really silly! B-)

Comment: I had to turn off DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials as well as AdBlock.